# JSON calls to Facebook's Comments Count for each URL in calendar

Tags: jquery, facebook

I have a jQuery calendar, each day is linked to a dynamic page with Facebook comments plugin on it. Right now i can get the number of comments by calling Facebook's API like this:

```
    $(".comm").each(function(){
        var root = "https://graph.facebook.com/?ids=";
        var ids = "http://root.toUrl.com/";
        var callback = "&callback=?";
        var date = $(this).attr('href');
        var fecha = root + ids + date + callback;
        $.getJSON(fecha, function(data){
        for(comments_num in data){
        var user = data[comments_num];
        $('.iframecont').append(user.comments);
        console.log(user.comments);
}
});
});
```

Facebook lets you obtain the comments count through Graph API only for one URL at a time. So for a calendar with 30 days in it, you have to call 30 URLs to obtain each URL response. For example, to retrieve the number of comments for 5th of May 2011, the URL would be https://graph.facebook.com/?ids=http://root.toUrl.com/phpDynamicpageGenerator.php?date=2011-5-3&callback=?. I have to make the correspondent call for each day, decode the answer and append the result to a p inside each day div.

Data returns this:

```
{
   "http://example.com/": {
      "id": "http://example.com/",
      "shares": 72603,
      "comments": 14483
   }
}
```

User.comments would be in this case 14483.

This code retrieves the data correctly, but now each day '.iframecont' displays all the json responses in a row, like this: `62212221222...`

How can i distribute each response to its correspondent div so the correct number of comments are assigned to the right date?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the following html,

```
<div> <!-- div n-1 -->
<a href="someurl" class="comm">some text</a>
<p class="iframecont"></p>
</div>
<div> <!-- div n -->
<a href="someurl" class="comm">some text</a>
<p class="iframecont"></p>
</div>
<div> <!-- div n+1 -->
<a href="someurl" class="comm">some text</a>
<p class="iframecont"></p>
</div>
```

For each of the anchor tags with the class "commm", you extract the value of the attribute "href" and make an api call. The api call returns some json data. You parse it somehow [looking at the json you say is returned back, I dont understand why you need a for loop and why you are appending at every iteration; but I will ignore that for now]. Now you need to append it to the corresponding paragraph tag.

Ok. So rewrite your function as follows

```
$(".comm").each(function(){
    var root = "https://graph.facebook.com/?ids=";
    var ids = "http://root.toUrl.com/";
    var callback = "&callback=?";
    var date = $(this).attr('href');

    // important. read http://bonsaiden.github.com/JavaScript-Garden/#function.this
    var $that = $(this);

    var fecha = root + ids + date + callback;

    $.getJSON(fecha, function(data){
        // why is this for loop needed?? 
        for(comments_num in data){
            var user = data[comments_num];
            console.log(user.comments);

            $that.parent().children("p.iframecont").append("num_of_comments");

            // OR you can use this
            // $that.siblings("p.iframecont").append("num_of_comments");
            // what to use will be decided by the exact structure of your html. 
            // check out http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/
            // in my example, either method will work
        }
    });
});
```

Things to note. $that is just another javascript variable. We prefix the $ to indicate that its acutally a jquery object. Its normal convention. We cache a reference to the element for which we are making the api call. Now when the callback function gets executed, using the cached $that, we find the corresponding paragraph tag. In my example, the `<a>` and the `<p>` are both children of the `<div>` tag.

Your html structure may differ, so please refer http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/ and modify the traversal accordingly.

Comment: The problem is that user.comments will return all 30 results and append them all to that ID... I need a way to call each JSON object and append the result to it's source caller...

Comment: are you saying that user.comments contains the num of comments per day and that they are not separated by a space or comma or any delimiter? Actually could you update your question with details like what the variables data and user.comments actually contain. That will help everyone better understand your problem.

Comment: Sorry, i updated the question a bit for a better explanation... User.comments contains only the number of comments for one day, is the way Facebook provides the response: the comments related to a URL at a time...